# Auth0-lock react native deprecated

Tags: react-native, auth0, graphcool

```
const createUser = gql` 
mutation ($idToken: String!)
{ 
  createUser(authProvider: 
    {
       auth0: {idToken: $idToken}}) { id 
    } 
}
 `
```

https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock 
I can not enter idToken because the library is deprecated. How do I get Id Token

Answer (score 0):

react-native-lock is deprecated and you need to use [react-native-auth0]
(https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0)

you could check the [source code](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0/blob/master/auth/index.js) for the api calls.

which are

https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#authorization-code-grant-pkce-

https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#authorization-code-pkce-